# Finding the largest list in a definition of lists in lists?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a question regarding finding the largest list in a group of lists in scheme.

For example, we define:
(define manylsts (list (list 9 (list 8 7)) 6 (list 5 (list 4 3 2) 1)))

How would I go about finding the largest list in manylsts?
Thank you

Comment: Can you add what you expect the answer to be in your example?

Comment: (max manylsts) -> 3
(max (first manylsts)) -> 2

Comment: Do you care about nested lists?  Do you want to return the longest list?  Or an index of the longest list?

Answer (score 0):

You make a procedure that evaluates to zero if it's argument is not a list. (eg. `9`), then if its a list you `foldl` over the elements using `length` of the argument as accumulator with a `lambda` that does `max` between the recursion of the first argument with the accumulator. It would look something like this:

```scm
(define (max-children tree)
  (if <??>
      (foldl (λ (x acc)
               (max <??> (max-children <??>))) 
             (length <??>)
             <??>)
      0))
```

Of course there are many ways of doing this, including explicit recursion, but this was the first thing I though of.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this question as you asked it.

You said you want to

> finding the largest list in manylsts

Since you included a non-listed element inside `manylsts` you want to have a definition that tells you how big is an element (if is a list).

So I wrote the function `elemenlen` that returns the length of a list if the given element *is* a list and 0 otherwise.

```
(define elemenlen
  (λ (a)
    (if (list? a) (length a) 0)
    ))
```

Then I decided I was going to sort them in order of length and then return the first element. So I need a function that returns a `boolean` value to use it with `sort` function included in `racket/base`.

```
(define list<
  (λ (listA listB)
    (< (elemenlen listA) (elemenlen listB))))
(define list>
  (λ (listA listB)
    (not (list< listA listB))))
```

The first function returns `#t` if `listA` is smaller than `listB`. The second function returns `#t` if `listA` is bigger than `listB`.

Lastly, `biggestElement` does the whole trick, sorts the elements in list `L` in descending order (based on length) and returns the first element.

```
(define biggestElement
  (λ (L)
    (car (sort L list>)
         )))
```

The function is used like this:

```
>(biggestElement  '((3 2 1) 1 (1 (2 3) 3))
'(1 (2 3) 3)
```

That is just one way of doing it, there are other ways of doing it, keep it up and tell us if it helped you.

As you see, I decomposed the big problem into little problems. This is a very handy way of doing your DrRacket homework.